# SQL update column from varchar data type to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-express

I imported a txt file into my table column B which is of datatype varchar
the data is like 10.00 GB, 20 TB , 100 MB etc

```
column a     column b
host A       100 TB
host B       20 GB
host C       100 MB
```

I did try convert (int,column name) which returned error advising cannot convert data type varchar to type int

I can replace the GB with blanks but want to convert anything with Tb or MB to converted to GB. yes I don't want the TB or GB or MB to be displayed in my column B.just numbers.

may be good if i can store these values in a separate column with datatype as int and then delete my original column in the same table.

Please could someone help

Comment: always store the data in single format and application layer can show it in appropraite format, no need to store units in the database. Also first check if you can get the data in csv in single units, so you don't have to do any conversion in SQL layer.

Comment: I agree, I'm trying to set up a capacity management database to automate features.so ideally i will just receive the flat files and then try to convert these so that there is no additional work need to be done by other teams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the column using:

```
select t.a, t.b,
       cast(left(b, charindex(' ', b)) as int) as num,
       right(b, 2) as units
from t;
```

This assumes that the values are all in exactly this format.

You can put it in one column by using multiplication:

```
select t.a, t.b,
       (cast(left(b, charindex(' ', b)) as float) *
        (case right(b, 2) when 'GB' then 1.0
                            when 'TB' then 1024.0
                            when 'MB' then 1.0/1024
                            else 1.0
         end)) as inGB
from t;
```

EDIT:

You might have a problem if all the values are not in the format you expect.  You can you a case statement, something like:

```
case when b like '[0-9] %' or b like '[0-9][0-9] %' or b like '[0-9][0-9][0-9] %' then . . .
```

to verify that a number is actually at the beginning of the string.

Comment: I get an error saying incorrect syntax near as.do I have to run both the statements in order to achieve this ?

Comment: The split works however, where in your code it says as int , i have had to do this as varchar and works nicely.will need to try the second part of the code which is my main thing

Comment: @user4227443 . . . I actually tested the code on a (very limited) set of examples.  Your values may not all conform to the format.  See the edit I just made.

Comment: I didn't have to do the latest edit that you had provided,however i will need to find a way to actually commit this to my tables and the sum all the values by host (column a )hopefully varchar datatype during that time is not problem while doing the sum function.

Answer (score 1):

Since i exported from a txt file the columns contained these values together.
However I will still need to convert all TB's , MB's to GB which is like a common type.

I will also need to find the sum of column b for each and every host

ideally I have the capacity assigned to each and every and I'm trying to find the sum of capacity for each and every host.

Answer (score 1):

I know that 1000 is not the same as 1024, but depending on your exact needs, this is a pretty simple method:

`select cast(ROUND(replace(replace(replace(columnB, ' TB', '000000000'), ' GB', '000000'), ' MB', '000') ,0,1) as int) from t`

Comment: This still fails saying conversion failed while trying to convert varchar value 35.000000 to datatype int.In response @Gordon Linoff , will that still work where my current column datatype is varchar ?am using sql server express 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be best to store the file size type in a seperate column

```
column a     column b    column c
host A       100         TB
host B       20          GB
host C       100         MB
```